# System of 2nd order diff equations with $x_1(t), x_2(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, substitution

Could you help me with the following system of two equations?
I have browsed through the forum, but I haven't found a similar problem.
$$m_1x_1''(t) + k(x_1 - x_2)+ cx_1'(t) = 0$$
$$m_1x_2''(t) + k(x_2 - x_1) = D_0 \sin(\omega \cdot t)$$

I just need a method for solving it. An idea for a substitution.
I have tried $x_1(t) = r(t)\cos(at),x_2(t) = r(t)\sin(at)$, but I still can't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $v_1 = x_1' $ and $v_2 = x_2'$. Then (after rearranging) your system becomes a first order system of ODEs
$$ \begin{pmatrix}x_1'\\x_2'\\v_1'\\v_2'\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
-\frac{k}{m_1} & \frac{k}{m_1} & -\frac{c}{m_1} & 0 \\
\frac{k}{m_2} & -\frac{k}{m_2} & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\v_1\\v_2\end{pmatrix} +
\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\\frac{D_0}{m_2}\sin \omega t\end{pmatrix}, $$
which can be solved by standard methods (see e.g. [Solving nonhomogeneous systems of ODEs](https://math.berkeley.edu/~conway/Teaching/old/summer2016-2552bc/exercises/NonhomoSys.pdf)).